# aplying a video as a texture in awe.js

Tags: javascript, augmented-reality, awe.js

I am trying to make it so that when a marker is seen it will open a plane with a video. so far the marker works well and the plane opens with the video. however the video doesn't auto play in either mp4 or webm formats. I have read suggestion about having the button set to make the video play, however I am unsure as to how to do it. any examples on how to do this would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you solved this yet? And please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)